# Counting commas in between

Tags: iphone, count

I'm feeling noob. How do I count commas? I don't know how to do it. 
I want code that look something like this.

Label.text = found 4 commas!!

```
          NSString *str = @"100,000,000,000,000";
           NSRange detecting = [str rangeOfString:@","];
            if (detecting .length > 0 ) {
             // Count how many commas?
             // label.text = ???;
           }
```

Label.text = found 3 commas!!

```
          NSString *str = @"100,000,000,000";
           NSRange detecting = [str rangeOfString:@","];
            if (detecting .length > 0 ) {
             // Count how many commas?
             // label.text = ???;
           }
```

label.text = found 1 comma!!

```
          NSString *str = @"100,000";
           NSRange detecting = [str rangeOfString:@","];
            if (detecting .length > 0 ) {
             // Count how many commas?
             // label.text = ???;
           }
```

Entering noobie textbox ["343,433,463"] and I should have 2 commas.

```
          NSString *str = noobie.text;
           NSRange detecting = [str rangeOfString:@","];
            if (detecting .length > 0 ) {
             // Count how many commas?
             // label.text = ???;
           }
```

How do I this?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray * foo = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found %d commas", [foo count] -1];
```

Comment: I got an error. It says expect identifier on                    label.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found %d commas", [foo count] -1]; <--it shows red.

Answer (score 0):

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744) `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` or `componentsSeparatedByString:` and get the size of the array returned.